# NodeJS return not stopping the entire function

Tags: node.js, return, fs

I have the function, **enter**, that contains two fs.readFile functions inside and on the innermost readfile I'm checking to see whether a txt file contains a certain keyword, and if it does it should stop the entire **enter** function.

Her is what the **enter** function looks like:

```
async function enter(email, firstName, lastName){

  fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, data){
    parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

    email = parsedData.email;

    fs.readFile('./anotherfile.txt', function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if(data.includes(email)){
        console.log('Stopping function');
        return;
      }
    });
  });

  console.log('Continuing with function');
}
```

The problem is that when anotherfile.txt contains the keyword, it does not stop the entire function, it continues and logs, "Continuing with function" as seen in the code above.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: where is await of your async function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fs promises are available Node v11.0.0
>   or You can can convert like this `const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);`

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

async function enter(email, firstName, lastName) {

    try {
        let data = await fsp.readFile(fileName)
        let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        let email = parsedData.email;
        data = await fsp.readFile('./anotherfile.txt')

        if (data.includes(email)) {
            console.log('Stopping function');
            return;
        }


        console.log('Continuing with function');


    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend, not using the variable `fs` for `fs.promises` as it will confuse people reading your code who think that's the normal `fs` module, not `fs.promises`.  You can choose whatever other variable name you want.  In my code, I use `fsp` as in `const fsp = require('fs').promises;` and then `await fsp.readFile(...)`.  Another reason to use a separate symbol is that you may need to use both `fs` and `fsp` as some methods you may want to use are only on `fs`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for my situation because changing it to fs.promises causes my fs.readDir to not work anymore through which the enter function is called

Comment: print err and check log also check node version

Comment: @ManjeetThakur I have just installed the latest version of node and there are no errors, it simply doesnt run the readdir

Comment: check file name and please read documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of two things.

- You are using asynchronous File read, that is, the flow of code won't stop when this readFile is called. Instead, the program would keep executing in a normal fashion. And when the file read operation is completed, the callback function you supplied will be called with the corresponding error or data.
- The return statement is inside of the callback function, hence it will only affect that function.

You need to use `await` when you are dealing with asynchronous functions. Look that up [here](https://javascript.info/async-await)